# Adding a css class for a Django ModelForm

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following form in django which is based on a model(MiniUrl):

```
from django import forms
from .models import MiniUrl


class AddUrl(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MiniUrl
        fields = ['long_url', 'pseudo']
        widgets = {
            'long_url': URLInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}), 
            'pseudo': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}),
        }
```

I want to add a css class to the fields  `long_url`  and `pseudo` .
When i run the application on the local server i get the following error:

```
 long_url': URLInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}),                                                                                                                                                           
 NameError: name 'URLInput' is not defined
```

How can I fixe it, please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

URLInput is located at django.forms. so when you import
`from django import forms`
in form you should use

```
widgets = {
    'long_url': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}), 
    'pseudo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}),
}
```

if you want to write

```
widgets = {
    'long_url': URLInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}), 
    'pseudo': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'user-input'}),
}
```

then you need to import `URLInput` and `TextInput` directly.
`from django.forms import URLInput, TextInput`